# React.lazy not working in production mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, code-splitting

I have a react app running, and I wanted to add route based code-splitting using React.lazy to it.

Currently my code is,

```
import { PureComponent, cloneElement, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
...
export const CartPage = lazy(() => import(/* webpackMode: "lazy", webpackPrefetch: true */ 'Route/CartPage'));
...
<Suspense fallback={ this.renderFallbackPage() }>
    <NoMatchHandler>
       <Switch>
          ...
             <Route path="/cart" exact component={ CartPage } />
          ...
       </Switch>
    </NoMatchHandler>
</Suspense>
```

Only mentioned the relevant parts here to make it compact.

Now the problem is, in webpack-dev-server, it runs perfectly, but when I run npm run build, and go to `/cart` the code breaks. After following the [link mentioned for the error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=306&args[]=function%20i(e)%7Bvar%20r%3Breturn%20r%3Dt.call(this%2Ce)%7C%7Cthis%2CT()(y%3F!e.wrapperProps%5Bd%5D%3A!e%5Bd%5D%2C%22Passing%20redux%20store%20in%20props%20has%20been%20removed%20and%20does%20not%20do%20anything.%20%22%2BP)%2Cr.selectDerivedProps%3Dn()%2Cr.selectChildElement%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%2Ce%2Cn%2Cr%3Breturn%20function(i%2Co%2Ca)%7Breturn(o!%3D%3Dt%7C%7Ca!%3D%3De%7C%7Cr!%3D%3Di)%26%26(t%3Do%2Ce%3Da%2Cr%3Di%2Cn%3Dm.a.createElement(i%2CObject(O.a)(%7B%7D%2Co%2C%7Bref%3Aa%7D)))%2Cn%7D%7D()%2Cr.indirectRenderWrappedComponent%3Dr.indirectRenderWrappedComponent.bind(function(t)%7Bif(void%200%3D%3D%3Dt)throw%20new%20ReferenceError(%22this%20hasn%27t%20been%20initialised%20-%20super()%20hasn%27t%20been%20called%22)%3Breturn%20t%7D(r))%2Cr%7D&args[]=), this is the message

```
Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: function i(e){var r;return
r=t.call(this,e)||this,T()(y?!e.wrapperProps[d]:!e[d],"Passing redux store in props has
been removed and does not do anything.
"+P),r.selectDerivedProps=n(),r.selectChildElement=function(){var t,e,n,r;return
function(i,o,a){return(o!==t||a!==e||r!==i)&&(t=o,e=a,r=i,n=m.a.createElement(i,Object(O.a)
({},o,{ref:a}))),n}}
(),r.indirectRenderWrappedComponent=r.indirectRenderWrappedComponent.bind(function(t)
{if(void 0===t)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been 
called");return t}(r)),r}. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.
```

A couple of common troubleshooting which I already did

1. In the `CartPage` component, I have done `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartPage);`
2. React version is `16.13.1`

And the weird part is, `Received a promise that resolves to: function...`. It is a function! But then it complains `Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function`. It doesn't make any sense to me.

What could be wrong?

**EDIT**

The `Route/CartPage/index.js` has the following

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default class CartPage extends PureComponent {
     render() {
         return <h1>Test</h1>;
     }
}
```

I deliberately made it as simple as possible. But still the same error came. But with different parameters. Now the error is [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=306&args[]=function%20t()%7Breturn%20c()(this%2Ct)%2Cr.apply(this%2Carguments)%7D&args[]=)

```
Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: function
t(){return c()(this,t),r.apply(this,arguments)}. Lazy element type 
must resolve to a class or function.
```

**EDIT 2**

I removed the following lines from my `webpack.config.js`. And it started to work! Still no idea why though

```
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');
...    
plugins: [
    ...,
    new MinifyPlugin({
        removeConsole: false,
        removeDebugger: false
    }, {
        comments: false
    })
]
...
```

Comment: did you find any solutions? I have the same problem

Comment: No. And the weird thing is, I installed a fresh React, and React.lazy works fine there. Not sure what I did wrong in my project

Comment: please show us `Route/CartPage` code

Comment: you should use `default export` in this file

Comment: Can you share the code of `CartPage` file?

Comment: @felixmosh I edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: @nickbullock I did export default. I edited the question now. Please have a look

Comment: What happen if you render the `CartPage` component without router?

Comment: @felixmosh you mean `<CartPage />` instead of `<Route path="/cart" exact component={ CartPage } />`?

Comment: Yeah it is interesting if this is a issue with route

Comment: @felixmosh I tried that and it still gives the same error. I don't even know how to debug it. Because in the error itself, it's saying that it is a function. But then says it expects a function

Comment: Can u create a repo with a reproduction code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215384/discussion-between-jay-ghosh-and-felixmosh).

Comment: One possible reasoning could be that you haven't imported React in your component. Maybe try `import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That is not it. I used the `ProvidePlugin` of webpack to make `React` globally point to `react`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the question, the `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` was causing the issue for some reason. My guess is, they were saving function definitions as strings to save space, and using eval somewhere inside its logic. But that's just my guess.

Anyway, the [Github page for babel-minify-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin) says that it is deprecated, so I ended up removing that from my project, and using the [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) instead. Everything seems to work now, and the build time is also significantly reduced. My advice is, avoid using the `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` and use some other minification plugin instead